# Android Amazon S3 Upload. error 405

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying for several days to connect Amazon S3 to my Android project. I downloaded the example "https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples" "S3TransferUtilitySample" and everything works fine on it, I see the files through the aws admin panel.
I copied into my project "Constants.java" with the working settings, also copied "Util.java" without changes.

The purpose of my project is to record the file from the microphone and transfer it to the cloud.
Here is the singleton that should implement this operations :

```
public class RecorderHelper {
private static final String TAG = "UploadActivity";
private static TransferUtility sTransferUtility;
static private Util util;
static RecorderHelper singleton;
static Boolean RecordStateRecording;
private static MediaRecorder recorder;
private final String RECORD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/record.aac";
String fileName;

private RecorderHelper() {
}

public static RecorderHelper getSingleton(Context context) {
    if (singleton == null) {
        RecordStateRecording = false;
        singleton = new RecorderHelper();
        util = new Util();
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = util.getS3Client(context);
        sTransferUtility = util.getTransferUtility(context);
    }
    ;
    return singleton;
}

public void StopRecording() {
    try {
        if (RecordStateRecording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release();
            AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(RECORD));
            if (aacTrack.getSamples().size() > 1000) {
                CroppedTrack aacTrackShort = new CroppedTrack(aacTrack, aacTrack.getSamples().size() - 1000, aacTrack.getSamples().size());
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.addTrack(aacTrackShort);
                Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
                FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)).getChannel();
                mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
                fc.close();
                aacTrackShort.close();
                aacTrack.close();
            } else {
                aacTrack.close();
            }
        }

        File file = new File(RECORD);
        TransferObserver observer = sTransferUtility.upload(Constants.BUCKET_NAME, file.getName(),
                file);
        observer.setTransferListener(new UploadListener());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RECORD", e.getMessage());
    }
    RecordStateRecording = false;
}

public void StartNewRecording(String UUID) {
    StopRecording();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + UUID + ".aac";
    recorder.setOutputFile(RECORD);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
    RecordStateRecording = true;
}

private class UploadListener implements TransferListener {

    // Simply updates the UI list when notified.
    @Override
    public void onError(int id, Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error during upload: " + id, e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onProgressChanged: %d, total: %d, current: %d",
                id, bytesTotal, bytesCurrent));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState newState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + id + ", " + newState);
    }
}
```

}

However, the file does not appear in the cloud and the listener tells me about the 405 error. Here is the full text.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

> Unable to unmarshall error response (Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference). Response Code: 405, Response Text:

I'm ussing the latest SDK :
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
Not sure about stacktrace because because i just get a callback to my listener about the transfer fails.
API 22

Comment: What version of SDK are you using? Android version? Can you post the complete exception stacktrace?

Comment: Added to main post. Thanks.

Comment: The error you are getting is from here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/8d91ac8014c3b2643fd92560f890c58d11fbe069/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.java#L720. The SDK is not able to unmarshall the error response for 405. Can you check if on the S3 console, you have sufficient permissions to do the operations on your bucket? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTpolicy.html

Comment: did you find solution to this problem ?